# Markdown HTML w/ bookdown: Changing Figure Numbering

Tags: markdown, bookdown

I'm using **bookdown** to make a simple (one document) Rmarkdown document, knitting to HTML. I understand how to make figures with captions and reference those figures, but I would like to **change the numbering on my figures**. A simple example of what I'm doing is below.

````
---
title: "My Title"
author: "Me"
date:  "1/1/2016"
output: bookdown::html_document2
bibliography: refs.bib
---


```{r heatmap, fig.cap = "Plot showing blah blah"}
plot(mydata) 
```
````

The above code creates a figure labeled "Figure 1: Plot showing blah blah". I ***want*** the figure to be labeled "Figure S1: Plot showing blah blah" (note the "S" before the figure number). (I'm writing a supplement for a journal submission.) I have read into how bookdown works and it seems like I can easily accomplish this by changing one line in the `_bookdown.yml` file (see: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html). The problem is that I don't have a `_bookdown.yml` file, I don't know how to make one or how to link it to my .Rmd file. All I have is a .Rmd file that knits perfectly fine with working figure labels, etc.

Any help making, editing, and linking a `_bookdown.yml` file would be appreciated. Alternatively, are there any other ways to change the figure numbering? I don't mind the fix being annoying, I just want it to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

`_bookdown.yml` is a [YAML](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) file for optional settings for a bookdown project. See Yihui's [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/configuration.html) for an overview of available options.

You can easily generate such a file yourself, e.g., by saving an R script in RStudio with the .yml extension. There is no need for linking to link to the .Rmd file – it suffices to place it in the project directory.

The most basic `_bookdown.yml` that accomplishes what you need is

**_bookdown.yml**

```yaml
language:
  label:
    fig: 'Figure S'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I tried this (I now have a _bookdown.yml file in my project directory) and unfortunately, nothing has changed in when I knit my .Rmd file. My figure labels are still "Figure 1:". Do I need to change anything in my YAML header in order for this to work? Or knit my .Rmd file in a different way than usual?

Comment: That is strange. It should work if you hit the *knit* button. Maybe you didn't indent the code in *_bookdown.yml* as shown in my answer? It's important that there is a tab (two blanks) before `label:` and two tabs (four blanks) before `fig:`.

Comment: Yep, this fixed it. I only had one tab before the `fig:`. Thanks so much!